# Can I use inferential statistics from a "non-random" sample of 34000?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, sample-size

I have 10 years of data on football players individual games which works out to 34000 samples. Can I use this to draw inference about football players in general?

Drawing on 3 requirements of CLT this is what I see:

1) Is it independent? 
Yes, this 10 years of data is less than 10% of all football players ever played.

2) Is n>30? 
Obviously yes.

3) Random Sample? 
This one I'm hung up on. Should I have taken a random sample of the past 10 years? To me it is better to have a lot of observations. Can I use my large sample to draw inference on the larger population or should I be drawing inference on just the past 10 years of players?

Comment: I think you need to describe how the data was gathered, e.g., who are the players? Which games are included?

Comment: I don't get the notion that random sampling the data you have makes up  for biases in selecting the data you have. That's just throwing away good data to no useful end. The priority is not to have a good conscience about statistical inference; it's to understand the data you have. Would you take these results seriously _if they were a random sample of the same size_? can be a fair question, but your most important question is what patterns you can find in your data.

Comment: Independence bites at many different levels, e.g. individual players in time, cluster effects if teams do well/badly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Much of this comes down to the group you are trying to make claims about. If you are trying to make claims about football players in general including those from before the last decade, as you addressed at the start of your question, then sampling just the last ten years puts a systematic bias in your sample. If you wish to view your sample as part of the population of just players from the last ten years you may do this, but you then must re-evaluate your previous requirements. Considering: Is there any inherant selection bias within your sample? Do you have less than 10% of footballers from the past 10 years?

As a side note, if you can sufficiently prove that the results from the last ten years do not differ significantly from broader data then this data becomes more useful for that kind of generalisation. However, at that point, you'd probably have enough data on players in the past.